# Can OpenMPI guarantee order of received message come from the same process?

Tags: c, linux, parallel-processing, mpi, openmpi

For example, I use `mpirun -n 4` to start 4 processes. Process 0 receives messages come from process1, process2 and process3.  Process 1 sends messages in the order of `message0, message1, message2`. When process 0 receives these messages come from process1, can it guarantee that process receives these messages in the oder of `message0, message1, message2` ? I don't care about the total order of all messages come from all different processes, I only need to know whether it can guarantee the order of messages come from the same process . By the way, when I use `MPI_Send()` to send message, the size of message is limited, right? What about `MPI_Bcast()` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as `message0`, `message1`, and `message2` have the same `tag` and are sent within the same communicator `comm`, the MPI standard guarantees that `MPI_Recv(..., source, tag, comm, ...)` will receive the messages in exactly the same order.

The size of the message is limited by the implementation, but most modern ones support messages of more than 2 GiB of size. You have to use user defined datatypes though as `MPI_Send` cannot send more than 2<sup>31</sup>-1 elements at a time.

Comment: Jeff Hammond's BigMPI (https://github.com/jeffhammond/BigMPI) provides a bit of API sugar for the creation of a large user defined type.

Comment: This time I use MPI_Bcast() to send message, this message is an array, and its elements are double type. If the array has more than 500 elements, it cannot be sent out.

Comment: Are you calling `MPI_Bcast()` in all processes in the communicator?

Comment: Yes, so now I want to know whether this function can guarantee order or not.

Comment: whether MPI_Bcast() can guarantee the order.

Comment: Collective operations must be called in the same sequence by all processes in order to guarantee correctness of the operation. May be you should post a new question and show in it the code that doesn't work.